# WebRequest works the first time but fails the next

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a code that works with HttpWebRequest that:
1. sets request to a host to get specific data using a POST request
2. reads it from the host using a GET
3. deleting the requests from the host.

The second time I am trying this same scenario i get timeout on stage 1 - the first request to get specific data.

The thing is that if I run the exe again it will work again with the first scenario and fail in stage 1 in the second time.

The delay issue is not the cause tried it with different delays...

Comment: You'll have to show some code of how you're constructing and performing the requests.

Comment: You can't have "post" on the request and "get" on the response; a response doesn't have a method, it's just what you get after sending the request. There's also no such thing as "deleting" a request.